is it possible to get support for more advanced snippets than default in Visual Studio?
I'm creating some snippets for both VS and VS Code, and I would love all the features from the VS Code ones in VS. And the ability to define file extension types instead of just language. Is it possible to add support for more advanced snippets?
Any suggestions?

For this kind of thing, it's worth using Developer Community. Make sure you explain exactly what features you'd like in VS. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio

@DrewNoakes thank you, I\ve been looking for place to share coding concepts
